# What are 'Icebreaker' and merino wool clothes and where can you get them?

Tags: clothing

I read this [article](http://www.artofmanliness.com/2015/01/21/how-to-travel-around-the-world-with-just-a-20lb-backpack/) and it talked about Icebreaker and merino wool explicitly when traveling.

Can somebody share what Icebreaker is and what merino wool is?

Is it just the [brand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icebreaker_(clothing)) or something else as well?

I ask as Icebreaker is told/shared as something to be worn outside, an Icebreaker long-sleeved shirt rather than just as an underwear to minimize odor while traveling as well as insulation against all types of weather.

Update: Reading [this](http://www.peterjthomson.com/2012/02/business-of-merino/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travel.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about traveling.

Comment: @phoog Great minds think alike, eh. ;)

Comment: It is actually about traveling or are you saying that people travel without clothes and odor.

Comment: @phoog please share your thoughts and did you read the first hyper-link. It was explicitly about traveling.

Comment: @fkraiem you too ^

Comment: Icebreaker is a brand, merino wool is the material. Price differs a bit depending on the "weight". AFAIK, Icebreaker was one of the first to manufacture and sell this type of underwear (they sell other products too but underwear or "base layer" is where wool is most useful). There are other brands of merino wool base layers and those are typically cheaper (up to 50%) cheaper than Icebreaker. If you want more details, you could probably ask on the outdoors website (also look for "layering" and "wool" there to find relevant material).

Comment: @shirish if there is a travel angle to your question then you should make that explicit in the body of the question rather than relying on links.  Visitors to the site won't necessarily follow the links, and links will generally stop working at some point in the future.

Comment: @phoog did that :(

Comment: This question may be better suited to Great Outdoors?

Comment: @CMaster what, which Great Outdoors ? A basic websearch threw many links. At first I thought it was a stackexchange site, tried to search but didn't get anything, on the web, got a million hits, where should I go to find answer to my query ?

Comment: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merino wool is the wool from a merino sheep and known for its high quality wool.

In fact the wool has some special characteristics: 
- It has antibacertial properties resulting in reduced body odor. I have a couple of merino wool shirts and yes - I can wear them multiple days without problems.

- Excellent warmth-to-weight ratio
- It retains warmth when wet
- It draws sweat away from the body
- It is very soft

However, it is quite expensive and not every wool from a merino sheep is high quality wool (different sheep strains can be bred for meat or wool - but they are not ideal for all purposes at the same time)

If you are interested in more - [merino sheep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merino)

Comment: just saw how expensive it is, INR 4.8k/- for an underwear. INR 80 (1 Euro) x 60 = INR 4800/-.

Comment: Prices are also very depending on the seller/brand. Most outdoor brands are expensive. However, if you buy the last season stuff from "casual" outdoor brands you will find cheaper merino wool stuff.

Comment: please name some names so I can check them out if and when I get an opportunity. Also how to figure out 'last season stuff' . Please put it as answer if possible.

Comment: In my experience the first three of your four bullet points are true for all wool.

Comment: @phoog Yes, precisely, the thing is that merino wool can be worn comfortably directly on the skin, thus making wool's otherwise excellent properties available for underwear/base layer. The alternative isn't necessarily another wool but mostly synthetics (which have their advantages like durability and lower cost) or cotton (which is almost universally hated).

Comment: @phoog you are right, maybe i should have written "it is wool with all characteristics, but you can comfortably wear it on skin". However, most likeley next question would be "what wool characteristics do you mean?"